Book about a character who wakes up in another world or dimension when he falls asleep
I read this book in the '80s.
It's about a veteran who was wheelchair bound and when he fell asleep he woke up in another world or dimension that was sort of a Utopia. In this other world he did not have to use a wheelchair.
When he falls asleep in the other world he wakes up back on Earth, and he keeps going back and forth every time he falls asleep.
Also the people from the other world taught him telekinetics and possibly other things.
That's pretty much all I can remember about the book

Is it a book or a story? I thought of Pillar to Post by John Wyndham. "Terry lost his legs in an explosion and then something of his mind from constant use of strong painkillers. One day he wakes to find himself, with legs, in a futuristic place that is not as utopian as it first seems. Near-immortality has a price, and two people attempt to outwit each other to survive at all." He is transferred by a future scientist, doing an experiment.

@sueelleker No telekinetics there though, I think.

I was just reviewing this and was looking at the related posts below my posts and I think I found it. I think it is a book called 2150 AD

@KevinfromMichigan: You can post that as an answer. I'm going to put a placeholder in for now.

When you post your answer (and feel free to borrow any or all of mine), I will likely delete mine.

OK. I have ordered the book. I will confirm after reading.

Kevin has indicated in a comment that this may be 2150 AD, presumably the one by Thea Alexander.

You travel with Jon who lives in 1976. When his mind is in the sleep-state, the forces of the future world reach out to him and show him how things can be. Go with him on his perilous adventure - a mind-expanding exodus from the imperfect today into a better tomorrow. Discover the beauty and the emotional demands such a journey can bring. Explore the system of thought and action that can be achieved in the macro world. This is a novel you can't put down - a philosophy you can begin living with now.

This review mentions Jon's veteran status:

It's about a Vietnam veteran who falls asleep and wakes up in the year 2150. Each morning he wakes up bake in 1976. Jon wants to stay in 2150 with Lea and it's about his struggles to make it there for good.


This was the unaccepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278877/book-about-a-man-living-in-the-70s-or-80s-who-falls-asleep-one-night-and-wakes?rq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47008/what-70s-book-had-the-main-character-trying-to-achieve-a-higher-level-of-thinkin/47031#47031
